# laravel DB query select multiple tables without joining

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Raw SQL query here and what to know how to write this Raw query in laravel query builder

Here is the Raw Query :

```
SELECT tbl_stock.* , series.*, series_size.*, tbl_size.* FROM 
tbl_stock , series, series_size, tbl_size 
WHERE
tbl_stock.series_id = series.series_id AND 
tbl_stock.size_id = series_size.size_id AND
tbl_stock.size_id = tbl_size.size_id
```

I have Tried DB Query builder laravel but getting exception

```
$stock_info = DB::table(['tbl_stock', 'shades'])->get();
```

This gives me this

> Array to String Conversion Exception

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Whats the problem with using join ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam I Know join will work. But for more flexibility i use the raw query not i want to know is their any possible way to use query builder

Comment: Query builder us faster than Eloquent, so if possible then use it :D

Comment: @SagarGautam this is not always true. If you have a very "fat" model and "thin" joins then using eloquent is faster

Comment: Also is it just me or is the fact that `tbl_stock.size_id` is used to join with 2 different tables a bit suspicious?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should replace your archaic join syntax with modern syntax:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.*,
    t3.*,
    t4.*
FROM tbl_stock t1
INNER JOIN series t2
    ON t1.series_id = t2.series_id
INNER JOIN series_size t3
    ON t1.size_id = t3.size_id
INNER JOIN tbl_size t4
    ON t1.size_id = t4.size_id;
```

Then, use Laravel's query builder syntax to build your query in PHP code:

```
$stocks = DB::table('tbl_stock')
    ->join('series', 'tbl_stock.series_id', '=', 'series.series_id')
    ->join('series_size', 'tbl_stock.size_id', '=', 'series_size.size_id')
    ->join('tbl_size', 'tbl_stock.size_id', '=', 'tbl_size.size_id')
    ->select('tbl_stock.*', 'series.*', 'series_size.*', 'tbl_size.*')
    ->get();
```

Comment: can we write the same query without joining

Comment: @PavanBaddi No, I can't, because you need a join here.  To be clear here, your current query _is doing a join_, it's just doing an _implicit_ join, which is hard to read.  Don't use that syntax, use what I gave in my answer.